How do I access file and other directory? Home icon missing in 24.04
24.04 ; earlier Home icon was coming on desktop so that I can access file directory
now that is gone somewhere and completely helpless how to access file system?
anyone know how to open file explorer/ finder kind of thing ( what it is called in Ubuntu, Nautilius or what)
this is really frustrating.
Ubuntu always comes with surprise as soon as you install and setup few things.
tried to search Files but nothing display in search result. see attached screenshot


press the left windows key and type Files in to the search bar and click on the icon. After it has loaded right click on the icon in the Dock and select Add to Favourites.

not showing any such thing. attached screenshot

i am suddenly experiencing the same problem, amongst other things, on a fresh 24.04 install. I managed to open folders for a while and now i dont know what happened but the icon is gone from the task bar and if i type "files" the app does not exist

this worked for me; dont know whether correct or not

sudo apt install nautilus

then try

nautlius .

and when file manager opens; then from active window select Pin to dash option

Alternative
go to Settings > Apps and then click on Files  and then click on Open  and there you go.


interesting you have files there, missing from my settings -> apps. I ll try installing nautilus, i wonder why it is not installed
